# GWT Hosted mode : Connecting to 127.0.0.1

Tags: java, gwt

I've recently started to see a hang when testing GWT apps running in hosted mode. It hangs with the message "Connecting to 127.0.0.1"

The only solution is to stop and restart a few times. Has anyone else seen this?

If so, any ideas about the cause? I wondered if it was a firewall block. I'm using Zonealarm. If you are also seeing this, please add a comment to this question mentioning which firewall you use - maybe a pattern will emerge.

Comment: If you think it's the firewall have you tried turning ZoneAlarm off to see if that fixes the problem?

Comment: I have also Zonealarm running and had to set the java executable in program control to full access rights, i.e. set 'Server Internet' to 'Allow'.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a Mac?

Maybe you are affected by this issue:

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4712

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this sort of thing is usually a firewall problem - turn zonealarm off and then make sure that Windows firewall hasn't kicked on again (not unheard of!) If this works then just add a rule to allow GWT to act as a server / connect via localhost (adding the rule on java.exe should work.) If not can you confirm you've tried turning the firewall(s) off?